# What precision and recall values do you consider good when the problem is multiclass classification?

Tags: classification

There are about 20 classes. Could you provide me with an educated guess? It's for the evaluation of a text topic classifier.
Thank you

Comment: I am voting to leave this open. I don't think it's opinion based so much as field dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Questions like this (i.e. what is a good value of $R^2$ or precision or specificity or any other statistic) are almost always field dependent.  What is suspiciously good in one field may be disappointingly bad in another.

So, to answer your question, you should ask people who work in the field you are interested in (that is, whatever the classifier is classifying) and see what they say. Or look at the literature and see what other people have gotten.